# Is it possible to detect file location when running it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

Say I have a file called `calc.exe` ( for example).

When I go to CMD and I run `calc.exe` it runs  because Windows has PATH settings in its environment variables.

Path information is  also accessible via typing `path` in cmd. ( as we all know).

**Question**

But - Is there any command in cmd that shows me information like this :

```
c:\> locate_Where_It_Will_run_From calc.exe
```

Response :

```
c:\windows
```

I mean , the only solution which I see now is to run :

```
dir /s  calc.exe
```

And then to match results with the PATH information .

Is there any such command which will show me the information of my example above ?

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed. PC/win users don't know what "which" command is  , and probably don't use unix . It is a pure perspective in a windows world and should not be closed as duplicated as an alternative to "which" because people might not know what is "which" at first place. ( — but as your wish....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [recent](https://superuser.com/q/249725/1686) Windows systems, the command is **`where`**:

```
> where calc
c:\windows\system32\calc.exe

> where where
c:\windows\system32\where.exe
```

PowerShell has **`Get-Command`** for the same purpose.

Note that `where` only covers %PATH%, but launching apps via "Run…" via Start menu **additionally uses [App Paths](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/25/10189298.aspx)** from the Registry.

---

The Unix equivalents are `which (-a)` and `type (-a)` (the latter also includes shell-builtins).

Comment: What can I say , you're the man

Comment: Is this also the order of accessing? (when >1) http://i.imgur.com/8g52efQ.png

Comment: Yes, it's the same order as `%PATH%` is checked (left-to-right). (Also [about Notepad](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/28/563008.aspx).)